# Pass an object between viewControllers (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` named `mainScreenViewController` that present a tableView of reminders.
When the user selects the first cell (“Add reminder”) I present a `UIPageViewController` named `newReminderPageViewController` using `presentViewController: animated: completion:` and not using `UINavigationController`.

I have 2 `UIViewControllers` in the `newReminderPageViewController` (the `pageView`), one called `colourViewController` and the other called `titleViewController`. On `colourViewController` the user chooses a colour for the reminder and when the user swipes to the left (swipes to `titleViewController` using the `pageView`) the users chooses a title for the reminder.

On `titleViewController` you have also an “Add” button that creates the reminder (using a model class called `Reminder` and have 2 properties: colour and title) and go back to `mainScreenViewController` (using `dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion:`)

My problem is: I need to pass the new reminder that was created on `titleViewController` to an array called `reminders` on `mainScreenViewController`. I need the specific `mainScreenViewController` object that is under the `newReminderPageViewController` (the `pageView`) with all the information of it so I can’t create a new object (`newReminderPageViewController *nRPVC=[newReminderPageViewController alloc]init];`).

How can I pass the new reminder which was created on `titleViewController` to the `reminders` array on the existing `mainScreenViewController`?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: Use the delegation pattern. What language are you using?

Comment: Or use `unwind segue`, its pretty easy to implement, just revert of normal `segue`